# implementation if isnan to sampling an interval

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to run fseminf function

```
        f = @(x) (x(1)-2).^2 + (x(2)-0.2).^2;
        g = @(x,s) 5*x(1).^2*sin(pi*sqrt(s))/(1+s.^2) - x(2);
        lb = [-1,0];
        ub = [1 ,0.2];
        S = [0,1];

A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];


x0 = [0,0]; 
x = fseminf(f,x0,1,@seminfcon1,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
```

Where:

```
function [c, ceq, K1, s] = seminfcon1(x,s)
global S g

% No finite nonlinear inequality and equality constraints
c = [];
ceq = [];

% Sample set
if isnan(s)
    % Initial sampling interval
    s = [0.0001 0];
end
t = S(1):s(1):S(2);

% Evaluate the semi-infinite constraint
K1 = g(x,t);
```

This is the code I use for creating a finite set from S, which is an interval. I do not understand how it works, why do we use isnan function instead of just declaring s=[0.0001] (which by the way does not work). It is used for fseminf alghoritm, I took the code from an example.

Comment: We need more context. `s` is obviously defined before this, otherwise `isnan(s)` would throw an error.

Comment: I will update the whole context then.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fseminf.html#f476274): "On the first iteration S is NaN, so that some initial sampling interval must be determined by seminfcon."

Comment: hmm, okey so it just makes sure that there is an initial sampling, but I do not understand how the alghoritm checks the constraints for all s, moreover the result is incorrect...

Comment: The **Limitations** and **Algorithms** sections at the bottom of the documentation page I linked might be helpful, particularly the link to [fseminf Problem Formulation and Algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html#brnox1w).

Comment: Thank you very much @beaker this has been very helpful